# Why is Bootstrap's 1em is smaller than browser default?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-size

Can someone explain it to me, why is my 1em font smaller than browser default? I set font-size on my body tag and using `font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;` [image]

Comment: Why should they be equal? The browsers default is _not_ the base measurement unit. Also note that the `16px` probably used as a reference is _not_ a fixed, but an elastic unit too.

Comment: @arkascha Actually when used on `body`, they _are_ supposed to be equal. (Unless you change the `html` fontsize also, of course.)

Comment: @TrungVu can you add a snippet in the question with your code?

Comment: I've just updated my question. I want my font-size change it with browser setting. What would I do to be alright?

Comment: @TrungVu This is supposed top be all right. Can you create a code snippet (or a JSFiddle) that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap sets the font size of `<html>` to 10px, you need to override this to get the browser default:

```
html, body {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```